# Oracle WebLogic Configuration Wizard Not Open

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c

I installed Weblogic version 12c 12.2.1.0 on the windows machine. The jdk version I used was 1.8.102.
I did not have any problems related to the installation, but the configuration wizard is not working.
It shuts down immediately before the program opens.

I installed the same version on Oracle Linux 7 machine. Again the configuration wizard does not work.

When I run it through command line with ./config.sh -log = xx.log

```
2017-03-04 17: 24: 42,472 INFO [24] com.oracle.cie.domain.template.catalog.impl.OracleHomeLocator - / home / oracle / Oracle / Middleware / Oracle_Home / oracle_common is already in the list
```

I'm getting the output.

Comment: Retry after adding -log_priority=trace to your command line in order to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

May be you entered the incorrect weblogic url. You should check for the url from log when you start server instance.[Look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUjWV.jpg) .